# Twists of elliptic curves over finite fields with characteristic 2 and 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a finite field $K$. In Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, it is shown in Proposition 5.4. on page 343 that if the characteristic of $K$ is not equal to $2$ or $3$, then the equations of all twists of $E$ can be described explicitly:

[image]

**Question**: Is there a general description of the equations of an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form if $char(K)$ is $2$ or $3$?

In this [paper by Kronberg, Soomro, Top](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02893.pdf), I can see how many twists an elliptic curve over a finite field with characteristic $2$ or $3$ has but I did not see (yet?) how these equations would look like.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twists_of_curves Here under the "Quadratic twist" you have cases when $char(K)=2$ and $char(K)\neq 2$